# OpenGl Rendering Transparent .png with Random White Pixels

Tags: opengl, png, textures, transparent

I am working on a game with a friend and we are using openGl, glut, devIL, and c++ to render everything.  Simply, Most of the .pngs we are using are rendering properly, but there are random pixels that are showing up as white.

These pixels fall into 2 categories.  The first are pixels on the edge of the image.  These are resulting from the anti-aliasing going on from photoshop's stroke feature (which i am trying to fix).  The second is the more mysterious one.  When the enemy is standing still, the texture looks fine, but as soon as it jumps a random white line appears on the top of it.

[image]

The line on top is of varying solidity (this shot is not the most solid)

It seems like a blending issue, but I am not as familiar with the way openGl handles the transparency (our code for transparency was learned from the other questions on stack overflow though I couldn't find anything on this issue, however).  I am hoping something will fix both issues, but am more worried about the second.

Our current setup code:

```
glEnable (GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Comment: What wrapping mode are you using for the textures?

Answer (score 1):

Transparent areas of a bitmap also have a color. If it is 100% transparent, you usually can't see it. Photoshop usually fills white in these areas.

If you are using minifying or magnifying flags that are not GL_NEAREST, then you will have interpolation. If you interpolate in between two pixels, where one is blue and opaque, and the other is white and transparent, then you will get something that is 50% transparent and light-blue. You may also get the same problem with mimaps, as interpolation is used. If you use mipmaps, one solution is to generate them yourself. That way, you can ignore the transparent areas when doing the interpolations. See some good explanations here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/10302/messy-alpha-problem-white-around-edges.html

Why are you using png files? You save some disk space, but need to include complex libraries like devil. You don't save any space in the delivery of an application, as most tools that creates delivery packages have very efficient compression. And you don't save any memory on the GPU, which may be the most critical.

Comment: I'll look into that; I am only using .pngs because they are the file type I have done the most with in terms of using transparency.  Which file type would you suggest using?

Comment: Using the Windows 'bmp' format is trivial, source code for loading it fits on one page. But if you already have it up and working, then I suppose you may as well continue with png. If you are making a fully commercial application, you probably want to do your own proprietary format eventually. Make sure you study the licenses for devil, and other sub libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  Usually I am pretty good on remembering to check those, but I am taking my friend's word on it being the most useful and didn't in this case.

Comment: So, in the short term that was very educational on how things are done, but in the long run has not helped me solve the problem.  I have tried a bunch of the things that were suggested, but none of them get rid of either of the white artifacts.  I did not make my own mipmaps, but I am going to have a lot of images, so doing so is not a very viable option.  I appreciate the help, though.

Comment: Did you try using GL_NEAREST instead of GL_LINEAR? Also, setting property GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S and GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T to GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE instead of GL_REPEAT can help get rid of lines shown at texture border. The "repeat" function is used by interpolation of pixels near the border, even if you only intend to draw the bitmap without repetition.

Comment: @LarsPensjö: Offtopic: only typical 24 bit RGB bitmaps are trivial to load. There's also OS/2, RLE, paletted and whole other bunch of BMPs that may cause trouble. From that perspective PNG is not so bad choice.

Comment: @Krom: You are right, and then not. Thing is, you can choose yourself what formats you want to use. So there is no reason to handle complicated or obscure formats. Unless your application is meant for media conversion.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an artifact in your source PNG. Are you sure there are no such light opaque pixels there?

White line appearing on top could be a UV interpolation error from neighbor texture in your texture atlas (or padding if you pad your NPOT textures to POT with white opaque pixels). Thats why usually you need to pad textures with at least one edge pixel in every direction. That won't help with mipmaps though, as Lars said - you might need to use custom mipmap generation or drop it altogether.